# Exception Thrown in this block thats why page cannot be redirected

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

The operation has timed out

```
 objdbconn.OpenConn()
    msSQL = " select google_name,google_password from hrm_mst_temployee  " & _
                " where employee_gid='" & Session("employee_gid") & "'"
    objOdbcDataReader = objdbconn.GetDataReader(msSQL)
    If objOdbcDataReader.HasRows = True Then
        objOdbcDataReader.Read()
        Try
            user_password = objcmnfunctions.HttpDecodeFilePath(objOdbcDataReader.Item("google_password").ToString)
        Catch
            radnote.Text = "Problem Occurred While Decoding Password"
            radnote.Show()
            connect = 0
        End Try
        user_name = objOdbcDataReader.Item("google_name").ToString
    End If
    objOdbcDataReader.Close()
    objdbconn.CloseConn()
    Try
        Dim contactser As New ContactsService("test")
        contactser.setUserCredentials(user_name, user_password)
        Dim newEntry As New ContactEntry()
        newEntry.Title.Text = "(L)" & cbocompanyname.Text & "-" & txtcontactpersonname.Text

        Dim primaryEmail As New EMail(txtEmail_ID.Text)
        primaryEmail.Primary = True
        primaryEmail.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork
        newEntry.Emails.Add(primaryEmail)

        Dim phoneNumber As New PhoneNumber(txtcountrycode.Text & "-" & txtcontacttelephonenumber.Text)
        phoneNumber.Primary = True
        phoneNumber.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsMobile
        newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(phoneNumber)

        Dim name As New Name
        name.FullName = "(L)" & cbocompanyname.Text & "-" & txtcontactpersonname.Text
        newEntry.Name = name

        Dim ims As New IMAddress
        ims.Primary = True
        Dim feedUri As New Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"))
        Dim createdEntry As ContactEntry = DirectCast(contactser.Insert(feedUri, newEntry), ContactEntry)
        Dim value As String = createdEntry.ExternalIds.ToString
    Catch
        radnote.Text = "Problem in Accessing Google Account"
        radnote.Show()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It's better you run your code again but without using `try..catch` block that way you can easily figure out the fault by seeing stack trace. If still you can't figure out what the cause of misbehavior then do share the line number here.

Comment: Please explain what your issue is. What line is failing. What is the exception. What have you tried. Just posting a wall of code doesn't make it easy for anyone to help you.

Comment: exactly the line is while accessing Google Calender exactly the line is  Dim createdEntry As ContactEntry = DirectCast(contactser.Insert(feedUri, newEntry), ContactEntry)